# Logstash - Storing RabbitMQ Logs - Multiline

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash, multiline, logstash-configuration

I have been using ELK for about six months now, and it's been great so far. I'm on logstash version 6.2.3.
RabbitMQ makes up the heart of my distributed system (RabbitMQ is itself distributed), and as such it is very important that I track the logs of RabbitMQ.
Most other conversations on this forum seem to use RabbitMQ as an input/output stage, but I just want to monitor the logs.
The only problem I'm finding is that RabbitMQ has multiline logging, like so:

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 19-Nov-2017::06:53:14 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.27161.0> (...:32799 -> ...:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'worker'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

=WARNING REPORT==== 19-Nov-2017::06:53:18 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.22410.0> (...:36656 -> ...:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'worker'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

=WARNING REPORT==== 19-Nov-2017::06:53:19 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.26045.0> (...:55427 -> ...:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'worker'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection

=WARNING REPORT==== 19-Nov-2017::06:53:20 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.5484.0> (...:47740 -> ...:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'worker'):
client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

I have found a brilliant code example [here](https://github.com/misheska/logstash-sample-configs/blob/master/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf), which I have stripped just to the filter stage, such that it looks like this:

```
filter {
    if [type] == "rabbitmq" {
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^="
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
        grok {
            type => "rabbit"
            patterns_dir => "patterns"
            pattern => "^=%{WORD:report_type} REPORT=+ %{RABBIT_TIME:time_text} ===.*$"
        }
        date {
            type => "rabbit"
            time_text => "dd-MMM-yyyy::HH:mm:ss"
        }
        mutate {
            type => "rabbit"
            add_field => [ 
                "message", 
                "%{@message}" 
            ]
        }
        mutate {
            gsub => [
                "message", "^=[A-Za-z0-9: =-]+=\n", "",
                # interpret message header text as "severity"
                "report_type", "INFO", "1",
                "report_type", "WARNING", "3",
                "report_type", "ERROR", "4",
                "report_type", "CRASH", "5",
                "report_type", "SUPERVISOR", "5"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But when I save this to a conf file and restart logstash I get the following error:

```
[2018-04-04T07:01:57,308][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2018-04-04T07:01:57,316][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2018-04-04T07:01:57,841][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.2.3"}
[2018-04-04T07:01:57,973][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-04-04T07:01:58,037][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, { at line 3, column 15 (byte 54) after filter {\n    if [type] == \"rabbitmq\" {\n        codec ", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:42:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:50:in `compile_graph'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:12:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2486:in `map'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `compile_sources'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:51:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:169:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:40:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:315:in `block in converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:312:in `block in converge_state'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:299:in `converge_state'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:166:in `block in converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:141:in `with_pipelines'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:164:in `converge_state_and_update'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:90:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:348:in `block in execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:24:in `block in initialize'"]}
```

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In case you are sending your logs from the rabbitMQ server to logstash with filebeat, you should configure the [multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) indeed. The goal is to merge the lines starting with something else than a date with the previous line that started with a date. This is how :

```
multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
```

Note: I previously tried to merge any lines started with space characters `^\s+` but that did not work because not all warning or error messages started with a space.

**Complete filebeat input** (7.5.2 format)

```
filebeat:
  inputs:
  - exclude_lines:
    - 'Failed to publish events caused by: EOF'
    fields:
      type: rabbitmq
    fields_under_root: true
    paths:
    - /var/log/rabbitmq/*.log
    tail_files: false
    timeout: 60s
    type: log
    multiline.pattern: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
    multiline.negate: true
    multiline.match: after
```

**Logstash patterns**:

```
# RabbitMQ
RABBITMQDATE %{MONTHDAY}-%{MONTH}-%{YEAR}::%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}
RABBITMQLINE (?m)=%{DATA:severity} %{DATA}==== %{RABBITMQDATE:timestamp} ===\n%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I am sure they had good reasons to log in this odd way in RMQ `3.7.x` but without knowing them, it really makes our life hard.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a codec as a filter plugin. Codecs can only be used in input or output plugins (see [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/codec-plugins.html)), with the codec configuration option.

You'll have to put your multiline codec in the input plugin that's producing your rabbitmq logs.